# How to expire session in php?

Tags: php, session, set, timeout

I want to expire session after 45 minute.

Is there any **simple** way to that?

Should I change any config in PHP.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the ini_set function in PHP. Look at this code:

```
// Get the actual session timeout
$currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get(session.gc_maxlifetime);
// Set the session timeout
ini_set(session.gc_maxlifetime, 45*60);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , it's work.